# Cannot enable vsync in Cygwin/X

Tags: opengl, cygwin, sdl-2

I am trying to compile a simple game using SDL2 and OpenGL under Cygwin. When I ran the program, I found that the GPU usage is unusually high. Then I found that VSync was not enabled for the program. More specifically, `SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1)` returned neither 0 (success) nor -1 (failed), but an undocumented value 5. `SDL_GetError()` returns `glXSwapIntervalMESA failed`. Any idea on how to fix this?

Update: I tried to call `glXSwapIntervalMESA` directly, and found that it returned `GLX_BAD_CONTEXT`. Now it seems that the only way to force VSync is through the display driver settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin/X forces you to operate through an X11 server that runs on top of Windows GDI. The capabilities of that X11 server are very limited and not every optional feature in the book is supported.

If you don't need the parts of X11 other than GLX, then drop it and access the graphics system directly. The same goes for Cygwin and POSIX functions.

I.e. use MinGW to compile your program without Cygwin, and a SDL-2 build that uses the OS native functions for OpenGL context creation and management.